# jquery add method equals jquery selector

Tags: jquery

In jquery the add() method used to add elements to an existing group of elements 
for example `$("h1").add("p").add("span")` here adding `<p> and <span>` elements to an existing group of elements (`<h1>`):

So can we say that, the below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("h1").add("p span").add("span").add('div').css("background-color", "yellow");
</script>
```

is equals to the below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("h1, p span, span, div").css("background-color", "yellow");
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question? Currently it's hard to understand what your asking. Please provide more detail by editing your question so it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both statements would produce the same result. However, with jQuery's [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function, you not only can add CSS selectors, but also JavaScript and jQuery objects, in addition to HTML strings (though you would have to append any HTML strings to add them to the page).